# Echo multiple lines of text to a file in bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, shell-script

How do I write:

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
print "<h3>$count metal prices available</h3>";
```

to a file, index.php?

I've tried:

```
echo "$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
print "<h3>$count metal prices available</h3>";" > index.php
```

but I don't understand how to escape the double quotes that are in the input.

Would it be better to use something other than echo? I'd rather not rewrite the whole PHP script if possible (it's longer than the 2 lines given in the example!).

Answer (score 13):

There would be several ways to do so:

```
 cat >index.php <<'EOT'
 $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
 print "<h3>$count metal prices available</h3>";
 EOT
```

or

```
 echo '$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
 print "<h3>$count metal prices available</h3>";' > index.php
```

or

```
 echo '$count = mysql_num_rows($result);' >index.php  # overwrites file if it already exists
 echo 'print "<h3>$count metal prices available</h3>";' >>index.php  # appends to file
```

there are much more possible ways - use this as a starting point for test things...

Comment: I especially like the first one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In bash, all you need to do is replace the outer quotes with single quotes:

```
echo '$count = mysql_num_rows($result);                                                                  
print "<h3>$count metal prices available</h3>";' > index.php
```

If you need to do more complicated stuff, you can echo multiple times using ">>" which appends instead of overwrites:

```
echo '$count = mysql_num_rows($result);' >> index.php
echo 'print "<h3>$count metal prices available</h3>";' >> index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

My script to save multiline into a `.csv` file:

```bash
#! /bin/bash
while [ 1 ]
do
    sleep 1s
    str="\""$(date)"\""
    echo   ${str} >>333.csv
    
    # begin add next row
    echo ",\"" >>333.csv
    # append multiline result
    ps >>333.csv
    # end add next row
    echo "\"" >>333.csv
    
    # begin add next row
    echo ",\"" >>333.csv
    # append multiline result
    df -h >>333.csv
    # end add next row
    echo "\"" >>333.csv
    
    sed -i ":a;N;s/\"\n\,/\"\,/g;ta" ./333.csv
done
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).